# Mapping issue while having specific transfer object structure on each layer

Tags: c#, api, mapping, domain-driven-design, dto

Does it worth it to handle the extra mapping when having specific transfer object structure on each layer?

We decided to split our legacy monolithic .NET 4.7 API into several modular .NET 6.0/7.0 APIs, by sub-domains, introducing a new architecture.

Each API have a classical 4 projects solutions: web service (controllers), application (services), infrastructure (repositories) and domain.

We decided to have specific DTO on each layer:

- Web service layer has `RequestModels` incoming and `ResponseModels` outgoing
- Application layer only handles ATO (application transfer object)
- Infrastructure layer handle ITO (infrastructure transfer object)
- Domain layer obviously handle domain models.

My concerns is that choice of separated transfer object structure by layer means a lot (I mean a lot!!!) of mapping :

- EF entity to and from ITO (done in infra)
- ITO to and from DomainModel (done in domain; ok, we could get ride of those ones if repositories returns DomainModel directly, I know, It's the subject of another question though),
- DomainModel to and from ATO (done in application),
- ATO to and from Request/ResponseModel (done in web services).

Moreover, We decided to don't use Automapper kind of tools because of: performance issues, strong type issues, run-time rather than built-time errors.

Don't you think it means too much mapping and that's overkill?
Or do you consider it's a right architectural approach to keep each layer softly coupled?

Thanks to share your thoughts and experience about this purpose

Comment: It often helps to think about versioning and if that's something you end with needing. You might start without mapping and just plan the infrastructure to have that in the future just with a noop currently at the spot where mapping might happen when needed. For example if you need a change the surfaced API model (Controller) but at the same time need to support the old version of the controller you must map somewhere if the persistence shouldn't change. But however you do mapping test the mapping. Just thinking it does not perform or it might have issues at runtime is a bit thin.

Comment: Splitting will make is easier to isolate errors where the error messages will clearly indicate which layer has the error.